# Is there a way to compare the RGB values of a 1024x1024 bitmap with the values from an input file with only 1,048,576 comparisons?

Tags: c++, bitmap, rgb, pixel, cpu-architecture

What I did was:

Open an input file (txt) with the RGB values of 64 color entries.

Open another input file that is a 1024x1024 bitmap with color values (3 bytes per pixel).

Read from the txt file and allocate the values from that into an array of structures.

The array of structures holds R, G, B values and the name of the color in question.
Next thing that I did was read the bitmap for RGB values and compare them to the values in the struct.

I created a for loop with 1,048,576 as the limit and another for loop inside with 64 as the limit to compare the values. Problem is the count of comparisons will result in 67,108,864.
Theoretical minimum is 1,048,576.

This is what I have so far:

```
 for (int i = 0;!bitmap.eof(); i += 3)
{
    unsigned char red, green, blue;
    bitmap.read((char*)&blue, sizeof(unsigned char));
    bitmap.read((char*)&green, sizeof(unsigned char));
    bitmap.read((char*)&red, sizeof(unsigned char));
    for (int j = 0; j < 64; j++)
    {
        if (int(blue) == bmiColors[j].b && int(green) == bmiColors[j].g && int(red) == bmiColors[j].r)
        {
            //cout << "B: " << int(b) << " G: " << int(g) << " R: " << int(r) << endl;
                //cout << "Position: " << bitmap.tellg() << endl;
            bmiColors[j].matchCount += 1;
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            bmiColors[j].skipCount += 1;
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

How would you go about optimizing it? The hint that I got was to use the pixel color as the index into a table. Please help me out.

Comment: probably should use an unsigned char. RGB colors that you describe are normally [0:255]

Comment: What aspect of [cpu-architecture] are you asking about?  If you're counting comparisons in the source code, that's pretty far away from CPU internals or even assembly language.  With some loop unrolling you could do half that many comparisons (if you don't count a hash table access as a comparison).  Or if you're not meant to count loop overhead and I/O as compares, then yeah a `std::unordered_map` hash table can give you one compare per pixel.

Comment: With SIMD (like AVX-512) you could consider broadcasting each byte to a full vector, and do one (AVX-512) or two (AVX2) SIMD compares per component, then AND the compare masks together and subtract from an accumulator.  (To increment the appropriate byte of another vector).  That might not be faster than a hash table.  With SSE4.2 `pcmpestrm` for a 16-byte any-against-any compare, you could work in 4 chunks for 3 components, comparing 16 input pixels in parallel.  But only if you deinterleave into color planes first (for a single vectorl).  And `pcmestrm` even slower than `pcmpistri`.

Answer (score 2):

Using the pixel color as the index into a table may be problematic. The color `{255, 255, 255}` would have the index `16777215` (`255*65536 + 255*256 + 255`). It may or may not be too large. A similar idea could be to use some kind of `map`, like an `unordered_map` and store the 64 `bmiColors` in that and map them to the count found in the `bitmap` file.

Example:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <unordered_map>

// A class to store one pixel
struct RGB {
    uint8_t r;
    uint8_t g;
    uint8_t b;

    // compare two RGB:s:
    bool operator==(const RGB& rhs) const { return r == rhs.r
                                                && g == rhs.g
                                                && b == rhs.b; }

    // read one RGB from an istream:
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, RGB& rgb) {
        is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&rgb.r), 1);
        is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&rgb.g), 1);
        is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&rgb.b), 1);
        return is;
    }
};

// A specialization of `std::hash` for RGB to be able to use it in an `unorderded_map`:
namespace std {
template<>
struct hash<RGB> {
    size_t operator()(const RGB& rgb) const noexcept { return rgb.r << 16
                                                            | rgb.g << 8
                                                            | rgb.b; }
};
} // namespace std
```

The main program would then

- Create an `unordered_map`, `bmiColors`, by reading the file containing the 64 values.
- Read from the `bitmap` file and use `bmiColors.find` to see if the color exists.

  - If it exists, increase the mapped value.
- Print the result

```cpp
int main() {
    std::unordered_map<RGB, std::uint32_t> bmiColors;
    {
        std::ifstream bmi("bmi.bmp");
        if(not bmi) return 1;
        std::transform(std::istream_iterator<RGB>(bmi), std::istream_iterator<RGB>{},
                       std::inserter(bmiColors, bmiColors.end()), [](const RGB& rgb) {
                           return std::pair{rgb, 0};
                       });
    }

    if(std::ifstream bitmap("file.bmp"); bitmap) {
        std::for_each(std::istream_iterator<RGB>(bitmap), std::istream_iterator<RGB>{}, 
                      [&bmiColors](const RGB& rgb) {
                          if(auto it = bmiColors.find(rgb); it != bmiColors.end()) {
                              ++it->second;
                          }
                      });
    }

    // print the result
    for(auto& [rgb, count] : bmiColors) {
        if(count) {
            std::cout << static_cast<unsigned>(rgb.r) << ' '
                      << static_cast<unsigned>(rgb.g) << ' '
                      << static_cast<unsigned>(rgb.b) << ' ' << count << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```